# RStudio Not Producing PDF Book in Ubuntu Mate 18.04LTS

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, ubuntu-18.04, tinytex

I am trying to produce a pdf_document using:
- R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)
- RStudio Version 1.2.503
- tintex version 0.20

I received this error message when I went to the `knitr` and chose the PDF option in the drop-down menu.
I have multiple issues but I will start with:

```
TeX Live 2019 is frozen forever and will no
longer be updated.  This happens in preparation for a new release.

If you're interested in helping to pretest the new release (when
pretests are available), please read https://tug.org/texlive/pretest.html.
Otherwise, just wait, and the new release will be ready in due time.
TeX Live 2019 is frozen forever and will no
longer be updated.  This happens in preparation for a new release.

If you're interested in helping to pretest the new release (when
pretests are available), please read https://tug.org/texlive/pretest.html.
Otherwise, just wait, and the new release will be ready in due time.
tlmgr: package repository http://mirrors.concertpass.com/tex-archive/systems/texlive/tlnet (verified)
[1/1, ??:??/??:??] install: environ [2k]
running mktexlsr ...
done running mktexlsr.
tlmgr: package log updated: /home/mcc/.TinyTeX/texmf-var/web2c/tlmgr.log
```

**Oddly enough.** I was able to print out the `index.html` page which holds the first chapter, Preface. It was 4 pages but did not follow up with the rest of the .rmd files.

I am able to produce a git_book but not a PDF file of the entire doc.

I am very exasperated.

Comment: Could you try to `remotes::install_github('yihui/tinytex')`, restart R, `tinytex::reinstall_tinytex()`, and try to compile your document to PDF again?

Comment: Thank you, the two commands you suggested clear up the above error. However, I am getting: Error: Functions that produce HTML output found in document targeting latex output, ... by adding ... always_allow_html: true. I have added 'always...' I still get warning and 'delete _main.Rmd after you finish debugging the error'. :(

Comment: Sounds like you have HTML widgets in one of your documents. See: https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/html-widgets.html Then follow what the error messages tell you to do.

Comment: I am searching for one now. Thanks